# How I can export a table PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to export a table via script into the formats "csv or tab".
I tried to use the follow command: "select from doenca into outfile "C:\doenca.csv"".
But did not work.. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-copy.html

Comment: I tried  \COPY doenca TO doenca2 CSV HEADER..but didn\t work..thanks anyway

Comment: OK, worked, thanks a lot